# SVG Icon highlighting issue in mobile devices on click

Tags: html, css, svg

I have used SVG icons in my web page. When i click on it from a mobile browser, the browser show highlighting on the icon.
Can i disable that highlight appear?

Example:
[highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV7NF.gif)

Code:

```
<div class="ictg-before">
<svg fill="#262626" height="72" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="72" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
    <path d="M11.99 2C6.47 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.47 10 9.99 10C17.52 22 22 17.52 22 12S17.52 2 11.99 2zM12 20c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8zm3.5-9c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5S16.33 8 15.5 8 14 8.67 14 9.5s.67 1.5 1.5 1.5zm-7 0c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5S9.33 8 8.5 8 7 8.67 7 9.5 7.67 11 8.5 11zm3.5 6.5c2.33 0 4.31-1.46 5.11-3.5H6.89c.8 2.04 2.78 3.5 5.11 3.5z"></path>
</svg></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, it is not the thing with SVG itself, but general behaviour of clickable ("tapable") elements on your page. Regardless if it is a link or just an element that changes when active, it will get the highlight to show it is usable.

To remove it (or alter it if you wish so) I generally use this solution from CSS Tricks and recommend it:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Here is the link on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-gray-highlight-when-tapping-links-in-mobile-safari/)

It is not a standard solution tho: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)

Beware that `cursor: pointer` might prevent that from working!

I would look into `:active` and `:focus` adjusting to maybe find some fallback if you need wider and more secure support.

Comment: searched the whole web for the cursor: pointer bit, thanks a lot!